# ARKit plane detection is problematic on iPhone 6s

Tags: iphone, ios11, augmented-reality, xcode9, arkit

I have been working on ARKit tutorials, and using my iPhone 6s as a build device; the problem is `plane detection` in my experience does not seem to be as effective as the tutorials I watch (which use iPhone 7).

Have not been able to find anything online about whether plane detection is identical or not for the iPhone 6s vs newer models, does anyone have any similar experience?

Or any online resource clearly stating that plane detection will be identical no matter the supported device used (`iPhone 6s` and above, `iPad 2017`, `iPad Pro`).

To be clear, the question is: is `iPhone 6s` worse in plane detection vs an `iPhone 7` and above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My biz partner and I do a lot of work in the ARKit space. I have a 6S and he has a 7. We're constantly discussing and evaluating performance/accuracy issues with ARKit and have never encountered a scenario where ARKit plane detection (or any other facet of ARKit for that matter) differed between the two devices.

He was lucky enough to get his hands on an iPhone X for a short time, did some AR testing, and reported that accuracy/detection did noticeably improve. That's likely due to the massive improvements in the A11 Bionic, so I'd expect to see those gains on the 8 as well.

That's a totally empirical take, so ymmv...

Comment: Interesting about the improvement for iPhone X - at least seems that upgrading from 6s to 7 for sake of ARKIT performance is not worth it, thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 1):

I also experiencing sometimes tracking issues with Iphone 6s. Especially when I really really close to an object with the phone, or if I suddenly move my phone camera.

I think on newer devices ARKit works better.